# Reusing a date object in momentjs

Tags: javascript, filter, momentjs

I have a Javascript collection that am filtering. In the callback I am instantiating a new `moment` object which breaks the filter function.

```
var today = new moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
return this.collection.filter((vocab) => {
  let benchmarkDate = new moment(vocab.interval_benchmark_date).format();

  return benchmarkDate.isAfter(today);
});
```

Is it possible to instantiate the `moment` object before the filter and then reuse it in each iteration of the filter callback be resetting it with each new date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR - remove `.format()` from `let benchmarkDate = new moment(vocab.interval_benchmark_date).format();` and your filtering should work again.  `.format()` creates a date string value, not a moment object like it was before, so it does not have access to the original moment methods like `.isAfter()`

---

> Is it possible to instantiate the moment object before the filter and then reuse it in each iteration of the filter callback be resetting it with each new date?

**Yes**, and you most certainly *should* do this as `moment()` used in high quantities (loops like this possibly) incurs a non-trivial cost that may end up becoming your bottleneck in performance down the road.  The less `moment()` calls you make, the better.  Re-use everywhere you can (except when modifying with .add(), etc. because moment will mutate the data directly)

However in your particular instance here - your iteration of different date/time info is what is creating the different moments, which you could potentially avoid by mutating the same moment on every iteration (by using a `.reduce()` method to continuously work with the previous result)

---

Also, you are doing `let benchmarkDate = ...format()` which creates a `string` and then you attempt to run `.isAfter()` on it - which won't exist because it's not the `Moment` object anymore.  Since the result of the `.format()` is unused anyway, you can remove that and it should be fine.

---

Oh and the `moment()` function does not require the `new` keyword to return the object.